# Use xpath inside a loop with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer

I would like to get the items from a page using a config object to determine the bits of the item I want to output.

An example config item is:

```
const shop = {
  urlToScrape: "https://shop-address.com/",
  itemSelector: "//li[@class='itemclass']",
  itemTitle: "//h2",
  itemLink: "//h2/a/@href",
};
```

I then get each item from the page using XPath:

```
const itemsOnPage = await page.$x(shop.itemSelector);
```

Now I want to grab the `itemTitle` and the `itemLink` for each item

```
for(const item of itemsOnPage){
// Some solution
}
```

I have tried using `item.$x` but can't get it to work and I'm lost on what else to try.

Comment: Yup, `item.$x(shop.itemTitle)`? If this doesn't work, please share a [mcve]. As an aside, I'd use CSS selectors over xpath. Much cleaner to me: `li.itemclass`, `h2`, `h2 > a[href]` respectively.